# RAID5 won't mount on boot

Tags: raid5

I have 4 working RAID5 installed on Ubuntu 16 and cannot find out HOW to option them to mount on boot. 
They are both DOS  and GPT and work fine when mounted manually.

Comment: Have you entered them into the /etc/fstab file?

Comment: Can I use format directly from blkid ?    /dev/md0p1: LABEL="DOC" UUID="92f91148-a6dd-4d06-9276-83ba2e39ec07" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="6a551d9f-01"
/dev/md0p2: LABEL="DEV_ORIGINAL" UUID="506d7ca6-b09c-415b-a681-f7f71ec62513" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="6a551d9f-02"
/dev/md0p3: LABEL="MISC" UUID="922f42e6-6ab1-4cd0-bc82-2aee9868187f" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="6a551d9f-03"
/dev/md0p4: LABEL="BACK" UUID="d2af4a0a-ecaa-48bc-a80c-5dae8b20e5af" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="6a551d9f-04"

Comment: Do I have to add each /dev/sdx ? Or can I just add /dev/md0 ?

Comment: @JanHus you only add the md0 device. Did you get it to work?

Comment: Yes, but only when I use LABEL (only) instead of UUID or /dev

Comment: @JanHus I am glad you were able to get it to work. Would you say this question has been "answered"?

Comment: Yes and no. It seems that "LABEL" has replaced UUID , however fstab does nor seems to work using other symbols like "TYPE".  fstab needs better documentation.  Cannot honestly say my original question has been clearly answered.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the file /etc/fstab in order to have them mounted at boot

first do `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/` in order to get the uuid associated with the various raid devices. You can also use the command `blkid` to accomplish the same goal.

add the entries into /etc/fstab using whichever text editor you'd like. The format is

`<file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>`

so it will look like

`UUID=(Put uuid here)  /target-directory              filesystem  defaults    0 0`

I have a raid 5 device mounted to a directory at /mnt/raid5 with an xfs filesystem so my /etc/fstab file has this entry

`UUID=d1bcc3e6-a211-409c-b6b7-e86652c5fb54 /mnt/raid5  xfs      defaults    0 0`

replace "target-directory" with the actual directory you are targeting and the filesystem with whatever kind of filesystem you have on those raid devices (ext4, xfs, etc....).